# Issue With Using Cursor After Initial Pipe Is Closed – MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, haskell, database-cursor

I'm attempting to use a MongoDB Cursor in Haskell. I use a pipe (connection to my MongoDB database) to obtain the value of this cursor, then close the pipe and give the value of the cursor. After opening another pipe, I have errors when accessing the cursor, although the Haskell MongoDB docs state that:

> a cursor is not closed when the pipe is closed, so you can open another pipe to the same server and continue using the cursor.

at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-2.5.0.0/docs/Database-MongoDB-Query.html#t:Cursor

I have tried using cursors when the pipe does not close between the initialisation and usage of them: this does work, however this is not the solution I want to integrate into my web-app (I will want to use pooling in the future.) I am also left wondering why closing the pipe causes the cursor to no longer work.

I have looked through the MongoDB source code, and have only found one area where `closeCursor` is used (https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/blob/33f2aca7b736c34d915916bc978bc5435baae533/Database/MongoDB/Query.hs#L1214). I am not sure if the error I'm having is a problem with a mismatch between the documentation of the client and my actual MongoDB Community Server (v4.0.10).

I have created a reproducible example of an IO Action causing this error.

```hs
firstFiveOver20 :: IO ()
firstFiveOver20 = (DB.withDB . find  $ (select [] "test"))
 >>= (() <$) . DB.withDB . Database.MongoDB.nextN 5
```

`find`, `select`, and `nextN` are from the MongoDB package.
The function `withDB` is defined as:

```hs
withDB :: Action IO a -> IO a
withDB action =  (connect $ host "127.0.0.1") >>= (\pipe -> access pipe master databaseName action <* close pipe)
```

The expected result is for nothing to be logged (as I don't expect any errors). However, the error `ConnectionFailure Handle has been closed: does not exist` is given. From my perception, this seems to mean that the MongoDB Database is reporting the cursor as not existing. This either means that the Haskell client has closed it or it was closed by the MongoDB Database when the connection was dropped. These both contradict the statement in the docs (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-2.5.0.0/docs/Database-MongoDB-Query.html#t:Cursor).

Comment: @Carl I have referred to the connection to the database as the "pipe". I have referred to closing the pipe multiple times (e.g. " This either means that the Haskell client has closed it or it was closed by the MongoDB Database when the connection was dropped.")  and know that that is what causes the error. However I do not understand why it causes an error: the Haskell MongoDB docs explicitly state that: a cursor is not closed when the pipe is closed, so you can open another pipe to the same server and continue using the cursor.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I missed the main point of the question.  A quick survey of the code suggests it's entirely up to the underlying database.  Not sure why Mongo would be doing that.

Comment: Yep, I'm not sure how I should go about finding specific documentation / help about this behaviour.